# Why can I step through through my array going forward, but not backwards?

Tags: jquery

I have an array I'm trying to step through through in both directions each time a user clicks a button.  Each time I click next, it steps through correctly, however, if I click previous, it doesn't step through on the opposite direction.  Why?

**JS**

```
var i = 0;
var images = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Hola", "Adios"];

$("#next").on("click", function(){
    if(i <= images.length - 1){
        $("#result").children("p").remove();
        $("#result").append("<p>" +images[i++] +"</p>");
    }
})

$("#prev").on("click", function(){
    if(i > 0){
        $("#result").children("p").remove();
        $("#result").append("<p>" +images[i--] +"</p>");
    }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

**Edit:**  Here's what happens if I change the conditional for the previous button to be `if(i > 0)` which is also not what's desired.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nv25uod5/1/)

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate?"  I don't see any iteration here.

Comment: iterate:  to step through

I'll edit to question to avoid confusion though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this it works.

changes made:

```
var i = -1;



$("#next").on("click", function(){
    if(i <images.length - 1){
        $("#result").children("p").remove();
        i=i+1;
        $("#result").append("<p>" +images[i] +"</p>");
    }
})

$("#prev").on("click", function(){
    if(i > 0){
        $("#result").children("p").remove();
        i=i-1;
        $("#result").append("<p>" +images[i] +"</p>");
    }
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nv25uod5/4/)

Comment: Wow, coulda sworn I tried something exactly like this at one point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if(i >= images.length){` with `if(i >= 0){`

Comment: I updated the fiddle link to show what it does if I change `i > 0` when the previous button is clicked.