# Stepping through object items

Tags: javascript, jquery

Much like the question I asked last week, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729862/why-can-i-step-through-through-my-array-going-forward-but-not-backwards).  I am trying to do the same exact thing by creating an Images object instead of having them in an array.  Here's the code I have so far.

**JS**

```
var Images = {
    image1: {
        href: "Image",
        text: "Bleh"
    },
    image2: {
        href: "Image",
        text: "Helb"
    }
};

$("#next").on("click", function(){
    for(var key in Images){
        console.log(Images[key]);
    }
})
```

So instead of it stepping through array locations, **I'm trying to get it to step through each item with each click of the next button.**  Would it be done the same way as with stepping through an array?

I'm also not looking for anyone to write the code for me, just to give an explanation of how it would work.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case, why do want to use an object, if you need a list like data structure?

Answer (score 1):

Using the existing object structure it, one approach would look like this:

```
var currPosition = 0;
$("#next").on("click", function(){
    console.log(Images['image' + ++currPosition]);
})
```

That said, your object just lists them out as image1, image2 etc... which screams array to me. So if your structure were more like:

```
var Images = [{ href: "Image", text: "Bleh" }, { href: "Image", text: "Helb"}];
```

Then the code could look a little more clean:

```
var currPosition = 0;
$("#next").on("click", function(){
    console.log(Images[currPosition++]);
})
```

Comment: This will only work if the keys are in a format "Image[n]" and if they are in this format, then he should really use normally indexed array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
var i = 0;
var keys = [];

if(Images.keys != undefined)
{
    keys = Images.keys();
}
else 
{
    for (var prop in Images)
    {
        if(Images.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        {
            keys.push(prop);
        }
    }
}

$("#next").on("click", function(){
    console.log(Images[i]);
    i++;
});
```

Also note, that the Object.keys() method might not be supported by older browsers. If you want to deal with this, you might want to loop through the Images object and save the keys to same array yourself.

Comment: Images.keys(); isn't a function, it'll send an error

Comment: @Robert It is a generic function of objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: still getting undefined this way

Comment: @Robert see my edit. I added a check if the Images.keys() function is supported.

Comment: So since this is converting it to an array, wouldn't it make sense to just do this as a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

This approach converts the object to an array, which you can then step through one element at a time:

```
var arr= [],
    idx= 0;

for(var img in Images) {
  for(var key in Images[img]) {
    arr.push(img+': '+Images[img][key]);
  }
};

$("#next").on("click", function(){
  console.log(arr[idx++]);
});
```

[**Working Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLkv8tmt/)

---

The code above assumes there are two levels of objects.

The code below will recursively traverse any number of levels:

```
var arr= [],
    idx= 0;

function toArray(name, obj) {
  for(var key in obj) {
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      toArray(name+'.'+key, obj[key]);
    }
    else {      
      arr.push(name+'.'+key+': '+obj[key]);
    }
  }
};

toArray('Images', Images);
```

[**Working Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/hgf5bngc/)

Comment: So since this is converting it to an array, wouldn't it make sense to just do this as a multidimensional array?

Comment: It would, but I made it one-dimensional since you requested a method of stepping through the `Images` object one item at a time.

Comment: Ah ok.  So if I just had the images, there's no sense in even doing an object.  It would be more efficient to do an array?